# How to display a view that doesn't fill the screen?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to display a popup in a game and ask the player to press some buttons so they can proceed. I want to let a portion of the current view remain visible so that I don't need to recreate it in the modal popup. The information needed to make the decision is already presented in this view. I'm doing most of this using IB. What I can't figure out (if it's even possible) is how to display a view that is shorter that the screen height...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a modal view controller. Instead create/make your view (not a UIViewController), resize it as you need and add it to you view and remove it yourself when you are done.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not reliable Geoff. View controllers behind a modal view controller are assumed not to be visible so their views will be unloaded if you get a memory warning while the modal has been presented.

Comment: Interesting... unless you handle the memory warnings yourself.  Your views should be implementing the handler already and releasing anything that can be recreated in the viewDidLoad method.  This shouldn't really be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a subview.  It can't be done in IB, though, but it needs to be done in code.

Here's a simple example of a subview:

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200); //put the size/coordinates for your view here
UIView *theSubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
theSubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:theSubview];
[theSubview release];
```

Comment: Agreed, the presentation needs to be done in code. The view could still be defined in and loaded from a nib if that's convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I can't figure out how to do this in IB, this will surely work! Although I'm still hoping for an IB solution, since the screens aren't integral to the app and I've adopted the mantra... "write less code..." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

subclass UIView with a custom view that is transparent except for where you need it. then use this as either modal view or just by putting it on top of the stack hierarchy.

Also from your question it sounds like you might be interested in subclassing UIAlertView and creating the 'popup' that way. A good article on this is found at [Alert View with Prompt](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html) and also [Custom AlertView Background](http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert)

Comment: which link? i didn't look closely at the first one, but the second one is fine..and subclassing a public class is allowed?

Comment: When I was looking for a solution to this problem, I was told that manipulating the alert view like this wouldn't fly because it would "confuse the users" by changing apple default behavior.  Lemme see if I can find supporting docs...

Comment: I think, if I remember correctly, it's not the subclassing that is the problem, it's the fact it goes against the Apple Human interface guidelines.

Comment: oh wow. interesting. never had that problem, but my changes weren't drastic really.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those things that are completely subjective.  We are at Apple's mercy in that regard...

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this before.  What I did was create a view in IB and made the background transparent.  Then, I added a subview to that view in IB, and resized it to the desired size.  You want to make sure the subview is not transparent like the background.

Then I just displayed it via a `ModalViewController`

```
[self presentModalViewController:customModalView animated:YES];
```

This works great and you can customize the background.  For example, if you want a darker overlay (similar to the form sheet modal window), you could make the main view background black and change the opacity to 25%.  Hope that helps...

Comment: That was something I though might work as well, but I (still) can't figure out how to make the view transparent in IB.

Comment: Open the view and then open the view attributes explorer.  Near the top, there are two fields that are important for this: alpha and background color.  Set your background color, and then adjust the alpha as needed.  The lower the alpha, the more transparent the view will be...

Comment: I've managed to get the transparency while the modal view is loading, but once it is in place, it goes back to the white background. I got that by changing the background opacity of the modal view to 0%.

Comment: You can keep that opacity 100%  You shouldn't need to manipulate the view at all in the code.  If you set it in IB, you should be good just displaying the modal view.  Try adjusting the alpha in IB, and keeping the opacity 100%.  Also, double check you are not adding a subview anywhere else in your code.  That may cause the transparency to disappear...

Comment: Geoff, thanks. Starting to feel like a newbie! I set alpha on the modal view to .15 and I get a white background with the contained subview displayed at 15% opacity! What am I missing here?

Comment: Yeah that's the tricky part.  What I did was actually add 2 views to the main view.  Try making the main view's background transparent,  then add a view; make it black and change the alpha here.  Now from the MAIN VIEW, add the subview you want to be on top.  That way it's not a subview of the transparent view.  Confusing, but does it make sense?

Comment: A bit, but the 'main view' is still flashing transparent. He is what I have: A main xib and a modally displayed xib. In the second one I have changed the background opacity to 0%. Then two views inside that, one on top of the other. the rear one has a black background and 25% opacity the front one a yellow background and 100% opacity. When I load the modal view it flashes transparent the returns to white!?! Posted to www.fireheart.biz/TestModalView.zip if you would like to see it.

Comment: I am not sure why that is not working.  It looks like you are doing everything correctly.  Perhaps you could try adding the view as a subview instead of using a modal controller?  That is just as simple and functions similarly...

Comment: I'll try that and I'll also try rebuilding it from scratch. You know after you've clicked every button and checked every box six times over, things just aren't the same! Thank you VERY much for taking a look at that for me. I'll let you know how it all works out.

Comment: Geoff, Thanks a lot for the help, but I was not able to repeat your example. I even tried it on the device , thinking that it might be a simulator bug... Do you have any sample code that you would be willing to post?